# Free Hashtable memory

Tags: c, xcode, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to free the memory my hash table uses before my program exits, but I get this error:

```
anagram(14510) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103be0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

The following is my code I use to free the table:

```
for(temp=0; temp<NHASH; temp++){

    sp=statetab[temp];

    while (sp!=NULL) {
        test=sp;
        sp=sp->next;
        free(test->word);
        free(test);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, because it does free the word correctly. Any Ideas?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code.

Comment: Make sure that you initialize `statetab` with all zeros.

Comment: Do you ever add something to your hash table that hasn't been `malloc()`ed (e.g. a stack variable or a global variable)?

Comment: Yes I did in the beginning of my program. It was so small i missed it.

Answer (score -1):

Most resources claimed by your program (certainly memory space for data) will be deallocated on program exit automatically. Unless you need the space in your program (or it will be running for a long time after not needing the hashtable anymore) just don't worry.